# How to update data in datatable column

Tags: jquery, datatables

Can someone help me loop through all the rows in a datatable column and update the data in it? So far I've found a way to loop through a column:

```
var table = $("#my_table").DataTable();
table.column(2)
    .data()
    .each(function(value, index) {
        console.log(value);
        value = 'abc123'; //this does not work
    });
```

However, I'm not sure how to update that value.. Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

`column` returns aggregated data for the entire table. Loop through rows instead. There is a [**`every()`**](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().every()) helper function that makes life easier :

```js
table.rows().every( function ( rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) {
   var data = this.data();
   data[2] += ' >> updated in loop' //append a string to every col #2
   this.data(data)
} )
```

Demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/qx84jw55/**

Comment: I've been struggling getting this to work for me.  Saw this and tried it and WORKED! Thanks for this answer!

Comment: Yup, works like a charm. Why is it necessary to update the whole row though? Why doesn't a simple "this.data()[index] = value" work?